# Agrupando valores em Django

Tags: django, group-by, django-annotate

Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade em agrupar algumas informações, de models separadas.

Por exemplo: Tenho 3 models, uma chamada `Category`, outra chamada `Group` e outra chamada `Tools`.

Essas tabelas vão ficar o name e slug de categorias existentes, grupos existentes e ferramentas existentes.

Existe também uma quarta model chamada Final. Lá vou ter os valores de várias combinações entre categorias, grupos e ferramentas.

Eu gostaria de **organizar as informações** dessa forma:

- ### Nome do Grupo 1
- - #### Nome da Ferramenta 1
- - - Categoria 1
- - - Categoria 2
- - - Categoria 3
- - #### Nome da Ferramenta 2
- - - Categoria 4
- - - Categoria 5
- - - Categoria 6
- ### Nome do Grupo 2
- - #### Nome da Ferramenta 3
- - - Categoria 7
- - - Categoria 8
- - #### Nome da Ferramenta 4
- - - Categoria 9

**Models**

- Group (contem nome e slug de um grupo)
- Tools (contem nome e slug de ferramentas)
- Category (contem nome e slug de categorias)
- Final (contem grupo, ferramenta, categoria, valor1, valor2)

A organização que coloquei acima, seria o menu de informações. No caso, eu colocaria os links nas categorias. Então a **rota/link** ficaria:

`/grupo-selecionado/ferramenta-selecionada/categoria-selecionada`

Gostaria de saber se vou precisar organizar minhas informações manualmente ou se é possível agrupar dessa forma usando o próprio `ORM` do **Django**.

Answer (score 0):

Um forma de resolver isso poderia ser assim.

**models.py**

```
class Grupo(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Ferramenta(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    grupo = models.ForeignKey(Grupo)
```

Para ter a visualização que você menciona na pergunta, poderia ser algo como:

```
lista = Grupo.objects.prefetch_related('ferramenta_set').all()
for grupo in lista:
    print(grupo.titulo)
    for ferramenta in grupo.ferramenta_set.all():
        print(ferramenta.titulo)
```

Está simplificado, mas espero que o princípio tenha ficado claro.

Vale a pena dar uma lida na documentação do Django sobre [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).